# Is there a groupby function that can make a new dataframe from names up to a underscore?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to set up a script in pandas that can help me sort some data, i am working on how to do it, this is how far i have managed to come.
This is my first attempt at pandas.

My idea is: have a csv with 4 colums: 1 with name and 3 with data. I want to group the data based on the name, the names will always have a underscore + a  incrasing number at the end, and it will be diffrent.
I have yet to find out how to code it, so now im trying to break the data by simmilar characters.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd import matplotlib.pyplot as plt from matplotlib import style df = pd.read_csv("C:\Python27\Projects\Pandas\csv_testing\csvtesty.csv",header=None,names=['names','x','y','z','code'])
#df.set_index('names',inplace=True) g = (df.groupby(['names', df.names.str[:3]])) for names, names_df in g:
    print(names)
    print(names_df)
```

Sample of my csv:

```
e3_30,3232.77,652478.1833,112.100,10272
e3_31,3232.78,652478.1834,112.101,10471
e3_32,3232.79,652478.1835,112.102,10670
dawn21_1,3232.70,652478.1826,112.093,10869
dawn21_2,3232.78,652478.1834,112.101,11068
dawn21_3,3232.86,652478.1842,112.109,11267
dawn21_4,3232.94,652478.1850,112.117,11466
dawn21_5,3232.102,652478.1858,112.125,11665
```

I was trying to ge it to seperate them into dataframes with simmilar names.

Part of my output:

```
 names        x          y       z  code
0  d1_1  3232.27  652478.07  112.05   123
   names       x           y        z  code
9  d1_10  3232.4  652478.464  112.063  1914
    names        x           y        z  code
10  d1_11  3232.42  652478.577  112.065  2113
    names        x          y        z  code
11  d1_12  3232.44  652478.69  112.067  2312
    names        x           y        z  code
12  d1_13  3232.46  652478.803  112.069  2511
    names        x           y        z  code
13  d1_14  3232.48  652478.916  112.071  2710
    names       x            y        z  code
14  d1_15  3232.5  652478.1029  112.073  2909
    names        x            y        z  code
15  d1_16  3232.52  652478.1142  112.075  3108
    names        x            y        z  code
16  d1_17  3232.54  652478.1255  112.077  3307
    names        x            y        z  code
17  d1_18  3232.56  652478.1368  112.079  3506
    names        x            y        z  code
18  d1_19  3232.58  652478.1481  112.081  3705
  names        x          y        z  code
1  d1_2  3232.28  652478.08  112.051   322
    names       x            y        z  code
19  d1_20  3232.6  652478.1594  112.083  3904
    names        x            y        z  code
20  d1_21  3232.62  652478.1707  112.085  4103
    names        x           y        z  code
21  d1_22  3232.64  652478.182  112.087  4302
  names        x          y        z  code
2  d1_3  3232.29  652478.09  112.052   521
  names       x         y        z  code
3  d1_4  3232.3  652478.1  112.053   720
  names        x          y        z  code
4  d1_5  3232.31  652478.11  112.054   919
  names        x          y        z  code
5  d1_6  3232.32  652478.12  112.055  1118
  names        x           y        z  code
6  d1_7  3232.34  652478.125  112.057  1317
  names        x           y        z  code
7  d1_8  3232.36  652478.238  112.059  1516
```

All the examples i can find have diffrent names in the colum they want it to separete them by.
Some help or pointers would help me alot thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use split by `_` and select first lists by indexing:

```
g = df.groupby(df.names.str.split('_').str[0])
```